# What is the recommended way to install Git for use with VS and other tools?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I tried using the GIT provider built into Visual Studio 2013. Although it works in VS, other tools like PyCharm and SourceTree do not see Git as being installed.

What is the best way to install Git so it can be used by Visual Studio and my other tools like PyCharm, WebStorm, and SourceTree? I'd also like to know exactly why the Git provider doesn't get picked up by the other tools so feel free to explain that.

Answer (score 1):

The git provider in Visual Studio is private to Visual Studio and doesn't implement the git command line.  The other tools you mention rely on the git command line.  Since the git command line was designed for Linux, git packages for Windows generally provide a set of POSIX-like command line tools along with git.  You generally will also need a diff tool like Kdiff.  Visual Studio git won't use any of these, but your other open-source tools looking for git will.

The excellent GUI/Shell extension/Visual Studio extension [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/) packages everything you need together in one convenient installer.  Once you are using Git Extensions, you probably won't use the built-in Visual Studio provider at all.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like it's because of the option you selected upon installation.

On the Windows platform, via the [official installer](http://git-scm.com/download/win)  for Git, you are prompted 3 options on how to install it.

> 1. Using Git Bash
> 2. Using Command Prompt
> 3. Using Git Bash & Command Prompt

The option that you need, is #2 since PyCharm, VS, et. al. uses your `%PATH%` to find `git`.